# PWA doesn't show splash screen with IOS

Tags: ios, splash-screen, progressive-web-apps

I have trouble showing the Splash Screen on a PWA when used on an IOS device.

The problem occurs when I put in the code more than one label for the splash screen.

For example:

If I put the following line it works fine:

```
< link rel = "apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="1125x2436" href = "/ asset / img / splashscreens / apple_splash_1125.png">
```

But if I put 2 lines it does not work:

```
< link rel = "apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="1125x2436"  href = "/ asset / img / splashscreens / apple_splash_1125.png">

< link rel = "apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="750x1334" href = "/ asset / img / splashscreens / apple_splash_750.png">
```

I would appreciate if you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it was to remove sizes = "1125x2436" and add media = "(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px)"

Below I leave an example:

```
<!-- iPhone X (1125px x 2436px) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px)" href="/assets/img/splashscreens/apple_splash_1125.png">

<!-- iPhone 8, 7, 6s, 6 (750px x 1334px) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px)" href="/assets/img/splashscreens/apple_splash_750.png">

<!-- iPhone 8 Plus, 7 Plus, 6s Plus, 6 Plus (1242px x 2208px) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px)" href="/assets/img/splashscreens/apple_splash_1242.png">

<!-- iPhone 5 (640px x 1136px) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px)" href="/assets/img/splashscreens/apple_splash_640.png">
```